# AngularJS $http params vs data--how to get 'data' on server?

Tags: angularjs, servlets

Background: using AngularJS form to post data to a Java servlet.

Say I have some model in my $scope, from the form, called firstName:

**$http request in controller:**

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/CustomerTrackerApp/JSONManager', 
    params: { firstName: $scope.firstName }
}).then(function(response) {
     alert(response.data);
});
```

**doPost() method in Servlet:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    out.println("From Servlet: " + firstName);
}
```

This successfully alerts "From Servlet: {name entered in form}"

My problem is that the `params: { firstName: $scope.firstName, }` causes the fields to show up in the url, so I want to use:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/CustomerTrackerApp/JSONManager', 
    data: { firstName: $scope.firstName }
}).then(function(response) {
     alert(response.data);
});
```

How do I get the value of `firstName` from, `data: { firstName: $scope.firstName }`, inside my doPost() and save it in an array?

Thanks so much for the help, I've been Googling for a while and can't find my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution. In java servlet doPost() used InputStreamReader and BufferedReader:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = in.readLine();
```

Now you can easily manipulate data as a string using JSONObject:

```
JSONObject json;

try {

    json = new JSONObject(line); 
    String jsonString = json.toString();
    String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(json);

    for (int i=0 ; i < names.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + " : " + json.getString(names[i]));
    }

} catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```